# Can we Communicate twice from HttpURLConnection request in java?

Tags: java, servlets, httpurlconnection

I have client/server architecture , The problem I am facing is like this. Here `Client` is java program , connect using `HttpURLConnection` and server is a Servlet. Once Client make a request Servlet sends a file through Stream . and client will download it from Stream . This process is working fine . The problem is suppose if file was not successfully download in client , client has to send message to server so that it will send the file again (I want this to be happen without making new connection). How to achieve this in a single request. can anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you write an infinite while loop, which would keep connecting to the server until you get a positive response. I mean

```
// create your connection instance
while(true){

try{
// connect to server and get the file
break;
} catch (Exception ){ // do something}
}
```

Comment: yes my application is continuously connect to server every 10 sec.

Comment: thanks you , its time to logout here . can I contact u tommarow?

Answer (score 0):

In order to know that the client has a problem you have to send a new request. You just can't do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is similar to this one: [How to Reuse HttpUrlConnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256681/how-to-reuse-httpurlconnection)

Which in return got answered already in:
[Persistent HttpURLConnection in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304006/persistent-httpurlconnection-in-java)

The answer for your question remains the same: You set the `http.keepAlive` and `http.maxConnections` properties, and let Java handle the HTTP persistence transparently.

Now, I have reason to believe that both answers won't help you, because what you are normally interested in for file downloads, is not restarting the entire download, but continueing a previous download.

That question was also already answered in: [Java: resume Download in URLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414438/java-resume-download-in-urlconnection)

Hope this helps!